# How to grab value from a selected item from a menu made from an unordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I built a menu here from an unordered list. When you select one item it swaps the class to active. What I would like to do is after a user has selected an item, grab the value of the HTML or the data-target from this underordered list. In the example below I'd like to retrieve External or external and store it in a variable I can pass to ajax/php after the selection is over.

```css
.options {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 -4px 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.options:before,
.options:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.options li {
  padding: 4px;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% / 3);
}

.options li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #30343b;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transition: border-color .3s ease, color .3s ease;
  transition: border-color .3s ease, color .3s ease;
}

.options li a:active {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

.options li a.active {
  border-color: #0d71d9;
}
```

```html
<ul class="options">
  <li><a class="active" href="#" data-target="external">External</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="internal">Internal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="both">Both</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, use some javascript event handling. You know what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the `data-target` attribute from the clicked link, you can use [`getAttribute('data-target')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

If you want to get the clicked element `html` use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

***Note***: In the below example i get all the `data-target` and `innerHTML`. If you want only for the `active` ones, you either put this code in the function where you add `.active` class, either in the declaration of `link` you use `.options li a.active`

See snippet below.

```js
const link = document.querySelectorAll('.options li a');
for (let i = 0; i < link.length; i += 1) {
  link[i].onclick = function() {
    const dataTarget = this.getAttribute('data-target');
    const targetHtml = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(dataTarget, targetHtml)
  };
}
```

```html
<ul class="options">
  <li><a class="active" href="#" data-target="external">External</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" data-target="internal">Internal</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" data-target="both">Both</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe because it was with jQuery. I changed it to javascript

Comment: There's an issue with this code though.  It adds more even listeners than needed and it also doesn't respond to DOM changes.

Comment: @ChadMoran more event listeners that needed? what do you mean ? it listens to clicks on all links from a specific `ul`. And DOM changes ? again, which DOM changes ? in the context of the OP's question, this answer solves his specific problem.

Comment: I could use it in jquery or regular - thank you. @MihaiT  I didnt actually need to modify it in real time, I wanted to submit it via ajax after all are selected so I modied the code to taking the link[i] from the loop and assigning it to vars for the datastring for a POST via ajax for the pseudo-form!

Comment: @MihaiT, what @ChadMoran is pointing out is the fact that you're adding an event listener to each element. javascript events bubble up and down the DOM so you only need ONE on the `ul`like I did in my answer. Also, what happens if you add elements? Are you going to maintain logic to to create new event listeners every time? What about removing? Are you going to manually remove the event listeners?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to setup an event listener on the `ul` tag. Assuming you're using jQuery that supports `.data()` that reads attributes from the dom.

#### jquery version

```
$('.options').on('click', (a,b) => console.log($(a.target).data('target')));
```

#### vanilla js version

```
let optionsElements = document.getElementsByClassName('options');
if(optionsElements.length) {
  let options = optionsElements[0];
  let selectedOptions = options.getElementsByClassName('active');
  let selectedOption;
  if(selectedOptions.length) {
    selectedOption = selectedOptions[0].dataset.target;
  }
  options.addEventListener('click', event => {
    selectedOption = event.target.dataset.target;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can easily do that. Target the `a` tag which has an active class and grab its text by using `.text()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = $("a.active").text();
    console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="options">
  <li><a class="active" href="#" data-target="external">External</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" data-target="internal">Internal</a></li>
  <li><a  href="#" data-target="both">Both</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not about jQuery. This is about JavaScript.

Comment: @Joven, read the question. you need to grab the text after click event and store in variable

Comment: @AkhilAravind I just gave him an idea. We don't really need to do everything for him right? I think he has a common sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read `data` attributes you can do it with native JS.

From the MDN documentation:

> Any attribute on any element whose attribute name starts with data- is a data attribute. You could use getAttribute() with their full HTML name to read them, but the standard defines a simpler way: a DOMStringMap you can read out via a dataset property.

So, after you get the element with the `active` class,

```
var element = document.getElementsByClass('active')[0]
```

You can either use `getAttribute()`, like this:

```
element.getAttribute('data-target')
```

Or the `dataset` property, like this:

```
element.dataset.target
```

> To get a data attribute through the dataset object, get the property by the part of the attribute name after data- (note that dashes are converted to camelCase).

If you want more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes